# Is this an Alternative Proof of a set of vectors forming a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**This is one of my exam past paper question**

[image]

So I proved this correctly by following the normal method which is showing that a, b and c are **linearly independant** My proof -

[image]

When I looked at the Answers, this was there ofcourse, and my method was correct. But, there was an **alternative solution** in the book, that I cant understand. Which is -

[image]

Now it seems like they are showing that the determinant is not zero, therefore it is a basis. But what is this ? How is this working ? I mean I was only aware of the first method that I always follow. Can someone tell me more about this? How is showing the determinant not equal  to zero a proof and why does it work? And obviously if my book is right, thatshowing that a set of vectors in a space is a basis by the determinant then isnt it so much more simple and requires less steps and less time than the first method I use.

Comment: How did you show they were linearly independent?

Comment: Ok wait il add that to my question

Comment: @Muphrid , i edited the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the [fundamental properties of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Linear_independence) is that its value is nonzero if and only if the columns of the matrix are linearly independent (in which case they are a basis of the vector space of all possible columns, because their number matches the dimension of that space).

This method will only allow testing linear independence for vectors already expressed in a basis, and only if their number equals the (finite) dimension of the space.

Comment: Yes but they are showing the determinant of the matrix is NOT zero, and therefore it is a basis.

Comment: Oops, I wrote zero where it should be nonzero. Corrected now.

Comment: Sir, so what does only expressed in a basis mean? I didnt understand that part. Much appreciated if you can make this part clear.

Comment: And also do you know any good link which contains the proof of this ? I really like to see why it works...

Comment: Expressed in a basis means in practice given numerically. Vectors in $\mathbf R^n$ are an example (the vectors _are_ columns of numbers) in which case one says they are expressed in the standard basis. If these are the only vectors you've ever been told about, ignore my remark. But vectors can be all kinds of things, like functions, and if I asked whether the functions $\sin$ and $x\mapsto\cos(x+\frac\pi2)$ are linearly dependent, a determinant could not immediately give the answer because these vectors have not been expressed in a basis.

Comment: Thank you sir, you made my understanding on this topic much better.

Comment: And to understand why _in general_ determinants detect linear dependence of $n$ vectors in dimension $n$, you first need to understand the general definition of determinants, which is not so easy. An ad hoc proof for the $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ case can be given though.

Comment: This would only work for n x n matrices? What about n x m?

Comment: No, the meaning of the sentence "only if their number equals the (finite) dimension of the space" in my answer is precisely that there is no single determinant that will tell you whether the columns of an $n\times m$ matrix are linearly dependent or not. A whole bunch of determinants will do (with any of them being nonzero sufficing for linear independence), but you will need $\binom n{n-m}$ of them, each a $m\times m$ determinant, making it not so attractive. For instance in $\mathbf R^4$ you need $6$ determinants $2\times2$ to check a pair of vectors (where inspection would in fact suffice).